# data integrity in sql server , using a mediator between users and actual tables of sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

is there any mediator kind of thing which acts as a layer between the users & the actual table, in sql server?

Like I want that when a user inserts data from my .net winform application , then firstly , it gets inserted into a mediator & then it goes to the actual table and gets inserted.

i want this because in case of a power failure as soon as the user inserts data , then my actual tables would be safe, only the mediator would be effected, and in the mediator i would use TRANSACTIONS to rollback and commit.

like i would use this: if mediator is fully updated with the new data then commit to it, and then insert to the actual table, else, rollback the mediator itself without touching the original table.

Comment: If you use transactions in your Winforms app, you get this behavior without an extra "mediator"

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use transactions directly for this? How many power outages are you expecting?!

Comment: That sounds like a DAL to me . . .

Comment: @marc_s : can VIEWS be used for this purpose? also, does C#.NET also has TRANSACTIONS , like SQL SERVER has?

Comment: @sqlchild: no views don't help. And **YES!** of course you have transactions in C# - either check out the `SqlTransaction` that gets started off the `SqlConnection` with the `.BeginTransaction()` call, or look into the C# `TransactionScope` construct

Comment: @sasfrog, sir , power outage could be anytime, its not known to us

Comment: @marc_s  : so i can implement Transactions in sql also and in .net also. but what would be purpose of using it doubly? shall i use it only in sql server or in both

Comment: @sqlchild: don't do it twice - **either** do it in T-SQL - always, all the time. In that case, you're probably either using stored procedures, or your SQL statements all include `BEGIN TRANSACTION`....`COMMIT` and stuff like that. **OR:** do it in your calling C# code. You need to pick one and stick to one.

Comment: @marc_s : ok sir, you mean to say that the mediator concept is not used anywhere. so according to you i should expose the users to my original tables

Comment: @marc_s : and for the security i should use logins, permissions and transactions and implement maximum validations on user input?

Comment: Logins/permissions have nothing to do with transactions. Login/permission define **access security** - is a user allowed to login, what can he do in the app? Transactions are for **data security** - make sure your data updates "make sense" and are either complete (or rolled back)

Comment: @marc_s: ok sir, so according to you, i should expose my original tables to end users to enter data in them directly?

Comment: @sqlchild: that's one approach, if you're using an ORM - if you don't like it, you need to create a layer of views (for reading) and stored procs (for anything else) to abstract away your database. Works, often very well - but requires more T-SQL coding.

Comment: @marc_s: sir, when we insert data in a table through a view , is a double copy of data generated in the database, i mean is the data present in the table and the view both?

Comment: @marc_s: if i use views for abstraction of my tables, and if i have 3 tables , which are updated from user input, then i have to use three views? is there any way of using a single view and update 3 tables simultaneously

Comment: @sqlchild: no - the view doesn't "contain" data - it's just a "shorthand" notation for a select on specific columns. A normal view doesn't have any data in it - it will assemble it from the tables as needed. No data is duplicated

Comment: @marc_s : are there other types of views also, as you mentioned : normal view.

Comment: @sqlchild: yes, there's a special case called *[indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)*; views that have a clustered index defined on them. Those are used for high-performance queries, and those will store the actual data on disk (e.g. you'd have data duplication here)

Comment: @marc_s: that's the same as when index is created on a table, then also duplication is done

Comment: @sqlchild: no - if you do a clustered index on a table, **no data duplication** occurs! But if you put a clustered index on a view, then the view is "materialized", e.g. the data contained in the view is actually physically stored on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the C# support for transactions - much better choice than adding yet another layer (mediator) to your system.

Read all about it on MSDN - [Transactions and Concurrency in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/777e5ebh.aspx)

Basically,  on your `SqlConnection` object, you have a `.BeginTransaction` method - use it to wrap any calls to your database in a transaction:

```
using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("your-conn-string-here"))
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, _con))
{
    SqlTransaction sqlTran = _con.BeginTransaction();
    _cmd.Transaction = sqlTran;

    try
    {
       _con.Open();
       // do something, e.g. call _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery, or read a data reader

       sqlTran.Commit();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        // log error
        sqlTran.Rollback();
    } 

    _con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL TRANSACTIONS can exactly cater your problem with-out any mediators. A transaction ensures that the action of the framed statements is atomic with respect to recovery. Transactions do not touch actual data until COMMIT is done. In case of a problem; ROLLBACK Statement terminates the current transaction and rescinds all changes made under the transaction.

Further, you can set the proper isolation for a transaction. Transaction isolation controls the visibility of changes between transactions in different sessions. It determines if queries in one session can see changes made by a transaction in another session.

Please read the [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx) for transaction for more clarifications.